# Operator IN in the sql query to jcrBrowser doesn't work

Tags: sql, magnolia

I have the folowing structure in my jcrBrowser

[image]

I want to select all the nodes which have a property "businessGroups" and have a value which will be equal to some of these numbers - 12, 10, 1. See below my query

```
select * from nt:base where jcr:primaryType='mgnl:component' and businessGroups IN ('10', '12', '1')
```

But this query doesn't work, I get an error:

```
Encountered "IN" at line 1, column 81.
Was expecting one of:
    "IS" ...
    "NOT" ...
    "LIKE" ...
    "BETWEEN" ...
    "(" ...
    "." ...
    "<" ...
    "=" ...
    ">" ...
    "<>" ...
    ">=" ...
    "<=" ...
```

So what the problem is? Is the syntax of my query incorrect or is this a problem with operator IN?
By the way, if I change my query like that

```
select * from nt:base where jcr:primaryType='mgnl:component' and businessGroups = '1'
```

everything works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really Magnolia specific, more JCR specific question.

The answer is simply that JCR search is not full SQL, but rather a subset of SQL directives. What JCR provides is SQL-like search functionality. And 'IN' is simply not supported. Please see [JCR specification](http://www.day.com/maven/jcr/1.0/8.5.3_SQL_EBNF.html) for SQL syntax (that's the syntax you are using in query above).

There is also JCR 2.0 specification, that defines [SQL-2 syntax](http://www.day.com/maven/jcr/2.0/6_Query.html) that is bit more advanced. You might want to switch to that. Or you can use xPath which is also supported for search.

HTH,
Jan